# Live Search Filter Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have problem in live search when i search the name the age will hide. i want is only the name can search it. and then the age not appear.

please check my code.

**this is my html**

```
<table class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span>wewe</span></td>
    <td>16</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span>Melvin</span></td>
    <td>18</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span>Marvin</span></td>
    <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**and this is my jquery**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var span = $(".AvailableGroupLab").clone().html();
function filter(element) {
    $('.AvailableGroupLab').html(span);
    var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".AvailableGroupLab span").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) == -1) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
       </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/REQEs/)

Comment: sir why the <th> tag is also appear ?

Comment: @wewe since it is the header of the table... IMHO it should appear

Comment: any idea how the <th> can`t appear?

Comment: @wewe change the condition to `return regexp.test($(this).children(':first-child').text())`, see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/REQEs/2/ - **I wouldn't recommend it**

Comment: i have problem with searching try to check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566973/checkbox-with-search-filter-codeigniter

Comment: arun try this jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/REQEs/2

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#src").keyup(function() {

    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(".name").hide();

       $(".name").each(function() {

        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

         if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
         {

             $(this).show(); 

         }

       });

    });
```

Comment: Could you add some text to explain your answer?

Comment: we use #src as search feild id when search feild press or type any text so run all the entire function.

Comment: first you load data from database or type some dynamic data into your div and give this name class but i use li's instead of div and my data loads from database. this keyup function just match each characters in my .name class li contents.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {

/*---- HERE WE FDEOUT AND HIDE DIV WHICH GRABL PRODUCTS LIST & PRICE ----*/

```
    $(".col-md-9 .show_this_li").fadeOut(500);
```

/*---- HERE WE START SEARCH FUNCTION ----*/

```
    $("#src").keyup(function() {

    $(".col-md-9 .show_this_li").fadeIn(500);
```

/*---- HERE WE FADEOUT AND HIDE 1ST DIV WHICH GRABL LIST WITH CATS HEADING ----*/

```
    $(".col-md-9 .hide_this").fadeOut(200);

    $('.clear_src').html("<h6>Clear Search</h6>");
```

/*--- GET SEARCH FIELD TEXT VALUE ----*/

```
     var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $(".hover").fadeOut(200);

      $('.error').html("").fadeIn(100);

       $(".hover").each(function() {

        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
```

/*---- CHECK SEARCH FIELD TEXT WITH LI PRODUCTS ----*/

```
     if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
         {

             $('.error').html("<h6>Please Wait...</h6>").fadeOut(200);
             $(this).fadeIn(300); 

         }else {
                //$('.error').html($('<h5/>').text("No Data Found"));       
            }



       });

    });
```

/*---- HERE WE FADEIN AND SHOW LIST WITH CATS WHEN USER LEFT SEARCH FIELD AND FIELD IS EMPTY ----*/

```
$("#src").keyup(function() {

   var val = $(this).val();

     if(val.length<1)
      {

            $(".col-md-9 .hide_this").show(1000);
            $(".col-md-9 .show_this_li").fadeOut(500);
            $('.error').html("<h6>Refressing...</h6>").fadeOut(200);

      } 

  });
```