# Checkbox with search filter codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My problem is when I check one of the checkboxs and then I search it, the checkbox will change to uncheck. and I don`t know what's wrong with my livesearch, it is not working.
please check this link to test.

http://jsfiddle.net/v921/KmVHf/4/

is is my javascript

```
var tr = $(".AvailableGroupLab").clone().html();
function filter(element) {
    $('.AvailableGroupLab').html(tr);
    var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".AvailableGroupLab tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) == -1){
            $(this).remove();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: nobody is calling the `filter` method

Comment: check this is http://jsfiddle.net/v921/KmVHf/11/

Comment: the problem is you are recreating those checkboxes every time... I had used a different approach in the last problem using hide/show... you need to use it

Comment: yeah but when i insert a checkbox. the data will hide.
try to put a checkbox sir. 
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/REQEs/2/

Comment: see the update below...  you need to change the column in which you were searching for the content.... using `:nth-child(2)` instead of `first-child` since the content is in second column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).children(':nth-child(2)').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input:text').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TxYqv/)

Comment: this is what i want:) but when i click checkbox the data will appear?

Comment: but this is great when i check wewe and then i search melvin. the wewe is already check again and nothing change it :)
but the only problem is when i click the checkbox it will appear? :(

Comment: @wewe not clear what you are asking... if an item is checked you don't want to hide it?

Comment: sir only children(':nth-child(3)') can i filter? not all with <td>?

Comment: its a simple question. please. last question promise :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711681/live-search-filter-with-checkbox-php?noredirect=1#comment27570570_18711681