# Live Search Filter with Checkbox PHP

Tags: codeigniter

I have issue about the live search with check box. My problem is when i search one the name list the check box is automatically check. only the showed data check.

example i search world "vin"
all have word vin must be checked.

this is my `[sample][1]`

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/v921/TxYqv/3/
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v921/TxYqv/3/

Comment: please clarify your question, what is your desired output?

Comment: @tolga sorry wrong explanation wait.

Comment: i want is . Example i search letter M. all have letter M must Checked.

Comment: what should happen to the previously selected items

Comment: it will be better to give a `select all ` button

Comment: else it could be messy like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zKwVe/1/

Comment: i want is example. i search "ven" all the "ven" showed ryt?. then all the checkbox have "ven" must Checked/TRUE.

Comment: please :) last question promise

Comment: only data showed must checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED answer:**

Here is how your js should look like:

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');    
    var $numberOfShownRows = 0;
    var $rows = $trs.filter(function () {   
        if($(element).val() != "")
        {
            $(this).children(':nth-child(1)').html("<input type='checkbox' checked />"); 
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children(':nth-child(1)').html("<input type='checkbox' />");
        }  
        return regexp.test($(this).children(':nth-child(2)').text());
    });  
    $rows.show(); 
    if($rows.length == 0)
    {
        $('#message').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#message').hide();
    }
}

$('input:text').on('keyup change', function () { 
    filter(this); 
})
```

And put this `div` whereever you want to put your text:

```
<div id="message" style="display:none"> No record! </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but here is not for chatting like conversations. Be careful about that.

Comment: Ok sir:) how to put a text when the data is empty? like no record found

Comment: are you there? i have a question

Comment: I am here. But as I said this is not a chatting platform. You should post new questions and maybe tag me.